# How to make an array of words from a file?

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame, text-files

I would like to create a function that reads the words in a text file, and then stores them in an array.

For example, if the text file said: `"John eats eats peas"`

The result array would look like `[John, eats, eats, peas]`

```
def countWordsInFile():
    array = []
    fileName = getUserText("Enter the name of the file you want to read array from")
    openFile = openNewFile(fileName,"read")
    i = openFile
    for words in i.read().split():
        print(words)
```

My question: How do I store the words into an array and print?

Comment: What does `print(words)` return?

Comment: prints out all the words in the file

Comment: example above, 
john (\n) eats (\n) eats (\n) peas

Comment: I think `i.read().split()` is what you're looking for. Print that instead of `words`

Comment: Is `john (\n) eats (\n) eats (\n) peas` a string or a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to append the word in your list `array`?

Basically, you have to initialize an empty list. In your case you called it `array`.
Your `words` contains all the words you want in your final `array`. You can do a double for loop to retrieve them and store them via the append.

```
def countWordsInFile():

    array = []
    fileName = getUserText("Enter the name of the file you want to read array from")
    openFile = openNewFile(fileName,"read")
    i = openFile
    for words in i.read().split():
        for word in words:
            array.append(word)

    print(array)
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to explain how it solves the OP's question.